# Rollup with @rollup/plugin-babel and Typescript: Expected ',', got ':'

Tags: typescript, babeljs, rollup

I'm struggling into this problem with Rollup 4:

> [!] RollupError: Expected ',', got ':' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
> src/index.ts (48:19)

My **Babel configuration seems to work fine**, I can run Babel directly and get the transplied output:

```
npx babel src/index.ts // Run perfectly fine
```

My `babel.config.json`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": "defaults"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

Now to my `rollup.config.mjs`. I was thinking about some problem in loading my external `babel.config.json`, so I just copied the Babel configuration into the `babel()` plugin:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/index.esm.js',
    format: 'esm',
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    babel({
      babelrc: false,
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            targets: 'defaults',
          },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Still getting the error. This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "lib": ["esnext", "DOM"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding `.ts` to the `extensions` configuration. Without it, Babel doesn't know that TypeScript files should be handled too:

```
extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.es6', '.es', '.mjs', '.cjs', '.ts']
```

Answer (score -1):

you will need a typescript compiler like `bun`, `esbuild` or anything else except `babel`:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/index.esm.js',
    format: 'esm',
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    typescript(),
    babel({
      babelrc: false,
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            targets: 'defaults',
          },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Not sure how this can help?

Comment: you need something other than babel to handle typescript using this plugin is standard

Comment: No. See my solution.